# Regex matching digit in between?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get number in between these strings.

```
strings = ["point_right: account ISLAMIC: 860328 9221 asdsad",
       "account 723123123",
       "account823123213",
       "account 823.123.213",
       "account 823-123-213",
       "account:123213123 ",
       "account: 123213123 asdasdsad 017-299906",
       "account: 123213123",
       "point_right: account ISLAMIC: 860328 9221"
      ]
```

Result would be

```
[860328 9221,723123123, 823123213, 823.123.213, 823-123-213, 123213123, 123213123, 123213123]
```

And i can do processing later to make them into number. So far my strategy is to get everything after pattern and anything before a letter. I have tried:

```
for string in strings:
    print(re.findall("(?<=account)(.*)", string.lower()))
```

Please help to give some pointers on the regex match.

Comment: `r'(?<=\D)\d[^A-Za-z]+\b'` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
(?=[^0-9]*)[0-9][0-9 .-]*[0-9]
```

Breakdown:

- `(?=[^0-9]*)` Lookahead for a word, such as "account", non-matching
- `[0-9]` Find a digit
- `[0-9 .-]*` Find any number of digits or special characters (in your strings you have spaces, dashes, periods so I included those)
- `[0-9]` Find another digit (to prevent spaces at the end)

Check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/X1Il1B/1), and sample code [here](https://regex101.com/r/X1Il1B/1/codegen?language=python)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!\W)([\d\s.-]+)(?<!\s)
```

The negative lookahead and lookbehind seems like overkills here but I wasn't able to get a clean match otherwise. You may see the results [here](https://regex101.com/r/4tAkmW/1)

`(?!\W)` Negative lookahead to exclude any non-word characters `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`([\d\s.-]+)` The capturing group for your numbers

`(?<!\s)` Negative lookbehind to exclude whitespace characters `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers must be the first numbers after the `account` substring use

```
re.findall("account\D*([\d\s.-]*\d)", s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kPyswb) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OlW1QU/1).

**Pattern details**

- `account` - a literal substring
- `\D*` - 0+ chars other than digits
- `([\d\s.-]*\d)` - Capturing group 1 (the value returned by `re.findall`): 0 or more digits, whitespaces, `.` and `-` chars followed with a digit.